# selectOneMenu ajax events

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using an editable primefaces selectOneMenu to display some values. If the user selects an item from the List a textarea should be updated. However, if the user types something in the selectOneMenu, the textarea should not be updated.

I  thought I could work this with ajax event out. However, I don't know which event I can use here. I only know the `valueChange` event. Are there any other events, like `onSelect` or `onKeyUp`?

Here is my code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="betreff" style="width: 470px !important;"  
            editable="true" value="#{post.aktNachricht.subject}">
            <p:ajax event="valueChange" update="msgtext"
                listener="#{post.subjectSelectionChanged}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{post.subjectList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:inputTextarea style="width:550px;" rows="15" id="msgtext"
        value="#{post.aktNachricht.text}" />
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The PrimeFaces ajax events sometimes are very poorly documented, so in most cases you must go to the source code and check yourself.

`p:selectOneMenu` supports *change* event:

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu ..>
    <p:ajax event="change" update="msgtext"
        listener="#{post.subjectSelectionChanged}" />
    <!--...-->
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

which triggers listener with `AjaxBehaviorEvent` as argument in signature:

```java
public void subjectSelectionChanged(final AjaxBehaviorEvent event)  {...}
```

Comment: Now event name is not necessary, we can just use <p:ajax update="msgtext" listener="#{post.subjectSelectionChanged}" />

Answer (score 13):

I'd rather use more convenient `itemSelect` event. With this event you can use `org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent` objects in your listener.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" 
        update="messages"
        listener="#{beanMB.onItemSelectedListener}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

With such listener:

```
public void onItemSelectedListener(SelectEvent event){
    MyItem selectedItem = (MyItem) event.getObject();
    //do something with selected value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Be carefull that the page does not contain any empty component which has "required" attribute as "true" before your selectOneMenu component running.
If you use a component such as

```
<p:inputText label="Nm:" id="id_name" value="#{ myHelper.name}" required="true"/>
```

then,

```
<p:selectOneMenu .....></p:selectOneMenu>
```

and forget to fill the required component, ajax listener of selectoneMenu cannot be executed.

Answer (score 2):

You could check whether the value of your `selectOneMenu` component belongs to the list of subjects.

Namely:

```
public void subjectSelectionChanged() {
    // Cancel if subject is manually written
    if (!subjectList.contains(aktNachricht.subject)) { return; }
    // Write your code here in case the user selected (or wrote) an item of the list
    // ....
}
```

Supposedly `subjectList` is a collection type, like `ArrayList`. Of course here your code will run in case the user **writes** an item of your `selectOneMenu` list.