# SelectOneMenu ajax does not work

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm working on project base on primefaces....
I'm trying to do as follows: JSF

```
<p:selectOneMenu        id          = "activeTin"
                        panelStyle  = "width:280px"
                        effect      = "fade"
                        var         = "t" 
                        value       = "#{homeBean.value}"
                        itemValue   =  "#{data}">

               <p:ajax  process     =  "@this" 
                        event       =  "change" 
                        listener    =  "#{homeBean.changeActiveTin}"  
                        update      =  "@this"/>

           <f:selectItems value     = "#{homeBean.valueList}" 
                          var       = "data"
                          itemLabel ="#{data.companyTinId}"></f:selectItems> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

selectOneMenu dose not enter ajax listener 
What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Check all these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Comment: Try to add `itemValue=#{data}` to `<f:selectItems>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selectOneMenu ajax events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587585/selectonemenu-ajax-events)