# How to display the value selected from <p:selectonemenu> inside <p:confirm> tag?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

There is one dropdown and one button. After selecting any item and clicking on button I have to display the selected item in the confirmation dialog, how to achieve this. I am using jsf and prime faces. Below is my sample code:

For dropdown:

```
<p:selectOneMenu
value="#{decRm.fi_templType}" styleClass="combobox"
id="temptypID" style="Width:30%" filter="true" onchange="selectedinput()">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="--#{lang.select}--" disabled="# 
{decRm.disableTemplate}"
itemValue="--Select--" />
<f:selectItems value="#{decRm.templtList}"></f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

For dialog box:

```
<p:commandButton  value="#{lang.gen_temp}"> 
<p:confirm header="Confirmation!" message="#{temptypID}" ></p:confirm>
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
<p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" onclick="generateTemplate('FI')" />
<p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Below is the front end screenshot. Suppose  I selected  T1 from list, I want to display T1 in the confirmation box.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In PF 5.1 I never got a `<p:confirmDialog` be updated via ajax. It always was only rendered once in the first GET. I didn't test if something changed to PF 6.2:

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your `decRm` managed bean is `@ViewScoped`, it should be enough just to ajaxify your `p:selectOneMenu` to set the value in the bean each time the selection is changed:

```
<p:selectOneMenu
  value="#{decRm.fi_templType}" styleClass="combobox"
  id="temptypID" style="Width:30%" filter="true" onchange="selectedinput()">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--#{lang.select}--" disabled="#{decRm.disableTemplate}"
      itemValue="--Select--" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{decRm.templtList}"></f:selectItems>
    <p:ajax update="my Dialog" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Then you only need to refer `#{decRm.fi_templType}` in your confirm dialog.

**See also:**

- [selectOneMenu ajax events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16587585/selectonemenu-ajax-events)

Comment: But you might need to update the confirmDialog from the `p:ajax`? I'm thinking of trying to add something to the `p:confirm` dialog that makes it lazy so it 'updates' its content right before opening...

Comment: @Kukeltje sure, this way involves having to update the dialog when ajax gets executed. It also could be done the way you state.